# Analysis function in disk approximated by polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function defined in an open set $U$ that contains the unit circle $C$. Prove that $f$ can be uniformly approximated by polynomials if and only if $f$ can be extended to an holomorphic function in an open disk $D$ that contains $C$.

I am not sure about the correctness of my ideas. If we suppose $f$ is holomorphic in an open set contaning $C$ then the Taylor series of $f$ is defined in an open disk that contains $C$ and converges uniformly to $f$ in $C$. Is this reasoning right?

Supose now there exist a sequence of polynomials that converge uniformly to $f$ in $C$. Then, since the sequence is differentiable $f$ itself is differentiable and therefore analytic. I am not quite sure this part is right, since I have not studied much about sequences of functions I don’t know if we need extra hyphotesis to ask for differentiability.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is not valid. It is given that $f$ can be approximated uniformly by polynomials in the given domain. This domain contains the unit circle but it may not contain the open unit disk.

Let $(p_n)$ be  a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly in the given domain to $f$. Apply MMP (Maximum Modulus Principle) to $p_n-p_m$ to see that $p_n-p_m$  tends to $0$ uniformly on the open unit disk as $n,m \to \infty$. Hence $(p_n)$ converges uniformly on the open unit disk to an analytic function $g$. [Uniform limit of analytic functions is analytic].  The function $F$ which equals $g$ in the open unit disk and equals $f$ on the part of te given domain outside the open unit disk is your analytic extension of $f$.

Comment: Could you explain what is the problem with my argument? What is MMP?

Comment: @Zanzag I have added an explanation.

Comment: Okay, so the idea is to prove $p_n$ is a Cauchy sequence on the unit disk so it converges to an analytic function. Is that right?

Comment: MMP stands for Maximum Modulus Principle. This is needed to show that $(p_n)$ is also uniformly convergent in the open unit disk. @Zanzag